# Basic MySQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

In MySQL, I need to create a new table called users with the following fields:

```
id – integer type (primary key)
first_name – varchar type
username – varchar type
password – char type with length 40 (this is the length of a sha1 hash)
type – varchar type (‘admin’ or ‘author’)
```

Everything looks straight forward except

```
type – varchar type (‘admin’ or ‘author’) .
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use MySQL's [`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/enum.html) datatype:

> An `ENUM` is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.

Therefore, in your case:

```
`Type` ENUM('admin', 'author')
```

Comment: Or a reference to a table userType.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ENUM datatype
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

```
`type` ENUM ('admin','author')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the user type won't be anything else besides `admin` or `author` you can use `ENUM`:

```
`type` ENUM('admin', 'author') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'author'
```

However, this might lead to an anti-pattern if the possible user types needs to expand or when you need to list the different user types in a form. If that's the case you can add another table:

```
user_types (type)
```

Where `type` is a `VARCHAR(20)` (which should be sufficient length). In your `users` table you create the same kind of field and add a foreign key to the `user_types` table.

---

Btw, don't store simple `SHA1()` of password, use [Bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add check constraint to the type.

```
Type CHAR(6) CONSTRAINT table_type_ck CHECK(Type IN ('admin','author'))
```

or

```sql
Type CHAR(6) CHECK(Type IN ('admin','author'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Enum is the collection of list
like numbers,days

```
ENUM('admin','author');
```